# Can I allocate a dynamic array without using `new` and just within iostream library?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I wonder if there has any other way to allocate a variable length array without using `new` and other libraries except for `iostream`.

Below is my suggestion. I know that a fixed array has a fixed size, which should be a constant, so I think that my implementation has satisfied the rules.

However, I don't know if those lines of code are appropriate yet? Can anyone help me confirm or explain why?

Really appreciate all the answers!

```
// ...
int n; cin >> n; int const x = n;
int m; cin >> m; int const y = n;

int a[x];
inputArray(a, x);
int b[y];
inputArray(b, x);
int const p = x + y;
int c[p];
// ...
```

Comment: `x` is not a compile-time constant, so `int a[x];` is not legal. If your compiler allows it, it does not conform to the language definition.

Comment: ***so I think that my implementation has satisfied the rules.*** Not the rules of standard c++. In the standard the array size must be a compile time constant.

Comment: Fixed-length arrays require a **compile-time** constant. `int n; cin >> n; int const x = n;` does not make `x` be a **compile-time** constant, it is just a **run-time** constant. Two different things.

Comment: Are you looking for `std::vector` perhaps? BTW: What does "just within the iostream library" mean for you?

Comment: @ulrich-eckhardt Oh, my apology. What I meant is that I'm only allowed to use the iostream library in my solution. Is this clearer to you? Thanks for your response btw!

Comment: @remylebeau  thanks for your answers! I couldn't distinguish between compile-time definition and run-time definition, but I can now! Thanks for your help again!